# Unable to download .gz file with requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

How do I properly download a `.gz` file? My code goes below:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.propertyshark.com/sitemap/CA-San-Bernardino-reports_1.xml.gz', headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Downloading...')
        file_name = 'file.xml.gz'
```

It does download gz file but it's corrupted - only `1KB` in size and when I try to unzip it adds `.gz.cpgz` in the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code and got the following error page. You seem to need to manipulate headless browsers such as Headless chrome via selenium. The Requests module applies to the condition of Bot mentioned on this error page.

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://www.propertyshark.com/sitemap/CA-San-Bernardino-reports_1.xml.gz")
print(res.text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The URL you are using doesn't fetch you the right `.gz` file, because it is an HTML page in reality, which downloads the `.gz` file using JavaScript. Since it creates a blank page, it looks like its the raw file hosted there but doesn't isn't actually like it.

I verified this by opening the page and inspecting its elements. This could be easily the case if the site uses some middleware to generate the .gz file on frontend.

If you can reach the developer for the site, you can get a custom path opened for you. Else, you may have to look into opening the URL with selenium and then download automatically.

It gets saved as a .gz file in your code right now, only because you provide that name explicitly - `file_name = 'file.xml.gz'`. FWIW, on linux, you can easily rename files of one extension to another.

Comment: hmm but if that's the case, if I download manually it gets downloaded?

Comment: @Volatil3 you are downloading manually with browser, the browser can obviously execute JavaScript and download it seemlessly for you. A simple test to understand if you can directly download an asset programmatically is to use `wget <url>` which throws a 405 in your case.